# Powers of Matrices

Tags: vba, excel

How do I write a VBA Macro that would take the power of a matrix (to an arbitrary user-specified power) that is located in cells A1 to C3?

Comment: what do you mean by power of the matrix? sample input and output would be useful.

Comment: Do you want to raise the matrix to a power? i.e. same as using Excel `MMULT` function multiple times? Or just raise each individual element to a power, which is fairly trivial? Because those are two different things.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Taking your question literally in the mathematical sense, this macro raises the matrix to a power (4 in the example) by repeatedly calling Excel's `MMULT` function.

```
Dim i As Long
Dim pow As Long
Dim vIn As Variant
Dim vOut As Variant

pow = 4 ' or whatever

' Fetch matrix from sheet
vIn = Range("A1:C3")
' Raise to power
vOut = vIn
For i = 1 To pow - 1
    vOut = WorksheetFunction.MMult(vOut, vIn)
Next i
' Write result to sheet
Range("E1:G3") = vOut
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the function below. Please note that, when the exponent is 0, the function returns the identity matrix, otherwise the matrix multiplied by itself the exponent number of times.

```
'Raises matrix to a power
Function PowerMatrixNew(rngInp As Range, lngPow As Integer) As Variant()
 'create identitu for power 0
 Dim identity() As Variant
 ReDim identity(rngInp.Rows.Count, rngInp.Rows.Count)

 Dim i As Integer
 Dim j As Integer
 For i = 1 To rngInp.Rows.Count
  For j = 1 To rngInp.Rows.Count
   If (i = j) Then
    identity(i, j) = 1
   Else
    identity(i, j) = 0
   End If
  Next j
 Next i

 PowerMatrixNew = identity
 For i = 1 To lngPow
    PowerMatrixNew = Application.WorksheetFunction.MMult(rngInp, PowerMatrixNew)
 Next
End Function
```

Answer (score -2):

There was a question like this some years ago which I remember because it was called matrix arithmetic but not as I was taught at school.

Fill cells A1:C3 with the numbers 1 to 9.  Set cell A5 to 2.  Select cells A7:C9 and type

```
  =power(A1:C3,A5) ctrl+shift+enter
```

and cells A7:C9 will be set to the squares of the values in A1:C3.  Change A5 to 3 and cells A7:C9 will be set to the cubes of the values in A1:C3.

The equivalent in VBA is:

```
 Range("a7:c9").FormulaArray = "=Power(a1:c3, a5)"
```

Comment: This does not take the power of a matrix. It raises each individual matrix element to a power (2 in this case), but that is not the same thing.

Comment: I agree, @ Jean-François Corbett, this is not matrix arithmetic as I was taught it. But it was presented as matrix arithmetic in the question I saw some years ago and I am sure I remember the term "power of a matrix". I had not previously come across ctrl+shift+enter nor FormulaArray so I spent sometime playing with the question and answer even though I had no immediate use for the information.  This question reminded me of the earlier one so I responded in case user1061701 was after the same information.

Comment: I have been Googling and found the question and answer I saw three years ago although they were not quite as I remembered.  The question was "How do you take a matrix to a power on Excel?" and the answer is at [Link](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20090502130515AA4IjPd).  This answer only deals with the Excel user side so I must have discovered the VBA version myself through recording the answer as a macro.

Comment: I guess the take-home message is: Just because it's written on teh interwebz doesn't mean it's true. There are a lot of terrible forum posts out there.